# HTML Video Issue

Tags: html, video, html5-video, mime

I'm trying to put a video on my website.  It plays in the explorer on my desktop but when i put it online it doesn't play (but it does on my mobile), it just shows a black screen with an 'x' in the middle.  I'm not using Apache or Wordpress, just HTML and notepad with fasthosts as my provider.

From the reading I've been doing online it may be something to do with the MIME type.  I've tried eveything but can't figure it out.

Here's the code so far...

```
<video width="360" height "203" controls="controls">
 <source src="Media\Videos\Water Video 2.mp4" type="video/mp4">
 <source src="Media\Videos\Water Video 2.ogg" type="video/ogg">
 <source src="Media\Videos\Water Video 2.webm" type="video/webm">
</video>
```

and the sole contents of the .htaccess file i have is...

```
AddType video/ogg .ogg
AddType video/webm .webm
AddType video/mp4 .mp4
```

Any help that could be provided would be brilliant.

Thanks in advance,
Paul

Comment: I had trouble like this one time on my rackspace box, turned out to be the fact there were no MIME types set for .ogg or .mp4. Adjusted those and poof...

Comment: http://www.feedforall.com/mime-types.htm <-- You can see what the mime types should look like here.

Answer (score 0):

First, I would try one of these along with your HTML5 embed:

http://videojs.com/

http://mediaelementjs.com/

These will help your videos play on browsers without HTML5 < video > support.

Second, be sure your meta-data is at the front of your mp4* so the file will play right away and not wait for the whole video to download. for the Webm file make sure it has low kbps (600kbps for example) so it can load on Android.

*This is what I use for that: http://rndware.info/products/metadata-mover.html

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for the advice but i've implemented your suggestions but it's still not working.  It looks like the video isn't loading but it does when i try the exact same code from the desktop.

Comment: Could you post a link to the live example? I would like to review the implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same black box with an x in the middle... Except this was for the HTML5 audio tag and I was only getting this error in IE 9.

For me, it ended up that I needed to change a setting in Internet Explorer:

Tools -> Internet Options -> Advanced -> Multimedia: "Play sounds in webpages".

Anyways, if this issue only happens to you in IE 9, I would check those Multimedia settings to see if there's anything you can change there that would make it magically come alive.

Hope that helps!